# Using Postgres, calculate count of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns are
  # max_spots

  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  # columns are
  # a_id

  belongs_to :foo
end
```

I need to get all Foos whose max_spots is greater than the number of bars associated to it but I need it to be done via active record and not by going through each Foos like

```
class Foo
  #bad
  def self.bad_with_spots_left
    all.select do |foo|
      foo.max_spots - foo.bars.count > 0
    end 
  end

  #good but not working
  def self.good_with_spots_left
    joins(:bars).select('COUNT(bars.id) AS bars_count').where('max_spots - bars_count > 0')
  end
end
```

I know I can just add a counter cache to foo, but just want to know how I can do this without that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not allow to use aliases in WHERE clauses but only column names.

As an alternative, you can try one of those those :

In pure SQL

```
def self.good_with_spots_left
  where('foos.max_spots > (SELECT Count(*) FROM bars WHERE bars.a_id = foos.id)')
end
```

or, with a bit or ruby (the second `select` is interpreted in ruby as it contains a &block)

```
def self.good_with_spots_left
  joins(:bars).select('foos.*', COUNT(bars.id) AS bars_count').group('bars.a_id').select{|foo| foo.max_spots > foo.bars_count}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The 1st solution in the currently accepted answer is inefficient as the co-related sub-query is executed for every row in the `foos` table. Using joins is a better approach for such scenarios.

The 2nd solution in the currently accepted answer doesn't work for `foos` without any `bars`.

*Eg: A new product without any orders.*

You have to use the LEFT outer join to address this issue. Apart from this, the count comparison can be done using the `having` clause. This way entire operation is processed in the database.

```
def self.good_with_spots_left
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN bars bars ON bars.foo_id = foos.id").
  group('bars.foo_id').
  having("foos.max_spots > COUNT(COALESCE(bars.foo_id, 0))")
end
```

**Note:**

The `COALESCE` command returns the first non null input. This command is SQL92 compatible so it will work across databases.

*Why are we using `COALESCE`?*

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` returns `NULL` value for `bars.foo_id` when there are no matching `bars` for a `foo`. The SQL `COUNT` operation doesn't like `NULL` values in the set, so we convert the `NULL` value to `0`.